# Gradle build error on Windows "Failed to create MD5 hash for file"

Tags: windows, gradle

I am running a gradle build on a existing project and I run into this error below.

> - What went wrong: Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task 'someTask' property 'destinationDir' during up-to-date check.
>
>   > Failed to create MD5 hash for file 'my_project_dir\.gradle\3.5\fileContent\fileContent.lock'.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

I ran with --stacktrace option, it complains about a file being locked in project_dir\3.5\fileContent, but not able to figure out what the issue is, any pointers are appreciated.

```
> org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to capture snapshot of
> output files for task ':someTask' property 'destinationDir'
> during up-to-date check.
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.snapshotTaskFiles(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:329)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.createExecution(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:153)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.access$100(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:61)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository$1.getCurrentExecution(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:111)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.getStates(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:203)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.isUpToDate(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:89)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:50)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:88)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:623)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:578)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:59)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:128)
>         at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:46)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:318)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:204)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:134)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:109)
>         at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
>         at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
>         at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
>         at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
>         at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>         at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
> Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to create MD5
> hash for file content.
>         at org.gradle.internal.hash.DefaultStreamHasher.hash(DefaultStreamHasher.java:40)
>         at org.gradle.internal.hash.DefaultFileHasher.hash(DefaultFileHasher.java:40)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingFileHasher.snapshot(CachingFileHasher.java:88)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingFileHasher.snapshot(CachingFileHasher.java:75)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingFileHasher.hash(CachingFileHasher.java:61)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.fileSnapshot(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:244)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.access$700(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:60)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter$FileVisitorImpl.visitFile(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:297)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.jdk7.Jdk7DirectoryWalker$1.visitFile(Jdk7DirectoryWalker.java:86)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.jdk7.Jdk7DirectoryWalker$1.visitFile(Jdk7DirectoryWalker.java:59)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.jdk7.Jdk7DirectoryWalker.walkDir(Jdk7DirectoryWalker.java:59)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.walkDir(DirectoryFileTree.java:154)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.visitFrom(DirectoryFileTree.java:132)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.visit(DirectoryFileTree.java:117)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.snapshotAndCache(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:192)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.access$500(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:60)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter$4.create(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:174)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter$4.create(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:169)
>         at org.gradle.cache.internal.ProducerGuard$StripedProducerGuard.guardByKey(ProducerGuard.java:115)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.snapshotDirectoryTree(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:169)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter$FileCollectionVisitorImpl.visitDirectoryTree(AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:98)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter$FileCollectionVisitorImpl.visitCollection(AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:82)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitRootElements(AbstractFileCollection.java:234)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitRootElements(CompositeFileCollection.java:185)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:53)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultGenericFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultGenericFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:38)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.snapshotTaskFiles(CacheBackedTaskHistoryRepository.java:327)
>         ... 107 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of
> the file
>         at org.gradle.internal.hash.DefaultStreamHasher.doHash(DefaultStreamHasher.java:54)
>         at org.gradle.internal.hash.DefaultStreamHasher.hash(DefaultStreamHasher.java:38)
>         ... 133 more
```

Answer (score 14):

The issue here is that the destination directory contains the `.gradle` directory, which is used by the initial gradle process and is thus locked in Windows. Then the daemon tries to hash the lockfile, because it hashes all files in the destination dir to check if the task is up to date, but since it is a lockfile, it can't be accessed by any other process.

The solution is to set the output directory of the task to a folder where it can't interfere with any locked files.

Comment: Thanks, how can we set this output directory for a build type?

Comment: or anybody else, this answer is good but we do not know what to do to "set the output directory of the task to a folder where it can't interfere ". How?

Comment: depends on your task really. For example the copy task has an `into` statement which declares the destination directory, while the build/compile tasks will put their stuff into the project buildDir by default.

Comment: I just deleted the `.gradle` folder and run it again. It works.

Answer (score 10):

Try run gradlew with this flag:

```
--project-cache-dir=../cache
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, thank you.

Comment: What's even stranger, is that if I set --project-cache-dir=./.gradle, i.e. the default cache folder it would use without setting that flag, it actually works. Seems like a definite Windows bug.

Comment: This helped me for lot of projects since ages but not working for one project, don't know why

Answer (score 1):

I used `rootProject.file` method and it fixed the problem:

```
task exportJar(type: Copy) {

    def fromDir = rootProject.file("app/build/myFile.jar")
    def toDir = rootProject.file("app/destination")
    from(fromDir)
    into(toDir)
}
```

Comment: Where did you place this task?

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue when had (in my %GRADLE_HOME%) two gradle properties files:

- gradle.properties
- gradle_copy.properties (then deleted)

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to this one, but deleteing `node_modules` and running `npm install` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to another Git branch and then back helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply all together exclude the .gradle folder from being included in the output jar file by doing something like this,

```
task createJar(type: Jar) {     
    archiveName('jarFile.jar')     
    String destFile = new File("path/to/jar").getCanonicalPath()     
    destinationDir(new File(destFile))      
    from('path/to/sources') {         
        exclude '.gradle'     
    }     
    with jar  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a `.gradle` directory from the project root worked for me as **@Max Peng** commented. Thank you Max!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by opening *PowerShell as administrator* and then re-running `flutter run`