# Gradle can't run my project tests on Windows 10 (error reading executionHistory.lock; multiple processes locking file)

Tags: testing, gradle, windows-10

I have a large Java desktop (non-Android) project with many submodules, and I recently started trying to get it to build and run on Windows 10.  (Normally I run builds on MacOS.)

We consistently get an error when trying to run the tests; this error happens on the Windows 10 machines from myself and also other developers on the project, starting from a fresh checkout of the code.

Here is the error:

`2020-11-09T18:21:51.995-0800 [INFO] [org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DirectorySnapshotter] Could not read file path 'C:\Users\Me\myproject\.gradle\6.6.1\executionHistory\executionHistory.lock'.`

Immediately after the error in the `--debug` logs is the following stack trace; I don't know if it's related, but it appears after every appearance of the error above:

```
java.io.UncheckedIOException: Failed to create MD5 hash for file content.
        at org.gradle.internal.hash.DefaultStreamHasher.hash(DefaultStreamHasher.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.hash.DefaultFileHasher.hash(DefaultFileHasher.java:41)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingFileHasher.snapshot(CachingFileHasher.java:87)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingFileHasher.hash(CachingFileHasher.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.SplitFileHasher.hash(SplitFileHasher.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DirectorySnapshotter$PathVisitor.snapshotFile(DirectorySnapshotter.java:281)
        at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DirectorySnapshotter$PathVisitor.visitResolvedFile(DirectorySnapshotter.java:260)
        at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DirectorySnapshotter$PathVisitor.visitFile(DirectorySnapshotter.java:238)
        at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DirectorySnapshotter$PathVisitor.visitFile(DirectorySnapshotter.java:173)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2804)
        at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DirectorySnapshotter.snapshot(DirectorySnapshotter.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultVirtualFileSystem.snapshot(DefaultVirtualFileSystem.java:146)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultVirtualFileSystem.lambda$readLocation$15(DefaultVirtualFileSystem.java:166)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultVirtualFileSystem.lambda$readLocation$16(DefaultVirtualFileSystem.java:166)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultVirtualFileSystem$StripedProducerGuard.guardByKey(DefaultVirtualFileSystem.java:203)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultVirtualFileSystem.lambda$readLocation$17(DefaultVirtualFileSystem.java:165)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultVirtualFileSystem.readLocation(DefaultVirtualFileSystem.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.impl.DefaultVirtualFileSystem.read(DefaultVirtualFileSystem.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.vfs.RoutingVirtualFileSystem.read(RoutingVirtualFileSystem.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter$SnapshottingVisitor.visitCollection(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractOpaqueFileCollection.visitContents(AbstractOpaqueFileCollection.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:326)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.lambda$visitContents$0(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.visitSingleFile(UnpackingVisitor.java:108)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection$UnresolvedItemsCollector.visitContents(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:380)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.visitChildren(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:292)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:326)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.lambda$visitContents$0(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.UnionFileCollection.visitChildren(UnionFileCollection.java:78)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:326)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.lambda$visitContents$0(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.UnionFileCollection.visitChildren(UnionFileCollection.java:78)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:326)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.lambda$visitContents$0(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.UnionFileCollection.visitChildren(UnionFileCollection.java:78)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:326)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.lambda$visitContents$0(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:86)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection$UnresolvedItemsCollector.visitContents(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:380)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.visitChildren(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:292)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:326)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.lambda$visitContents$0(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:86)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFileCollectionFactory$ResolvingFileCollection.visitChildren(DefaultFileCollectionFactory.java:310)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:326)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.lambda$visitContents$0(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.PropertyFileCollection.visitChildren(PropertyFileCollection.java:48)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:119)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:326)
        at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.AbstractFileCollectionFingerprinter.fingerprint(AbstractFileCollectionFingerprinter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.lambda$visitInputFileProperties$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:327)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.lambda$fingerprintInputFiles$3(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:192)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.visitInputFileProperties(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:325)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.fingerprintInputFiles(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:188)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.captureExecutionState(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:150)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.lambda$captureExecutionStateOp$1(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:104)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildOperationStep$1.call(BuildOperationStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:409)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:399)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:94)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildOperationStep.operation(BuildOperationStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.captureExecutionStateOp(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:103)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.lambda$execute$0(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:78)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:258)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:28)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:195)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:187)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:114)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:409)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:399)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:242)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:150)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:94)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:372)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:359)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:352)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:249)
        at org.gradle.internal.hash.DefaultStreamHasher.doHash(DefaultStreamHasher.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.hash.DefaultStreamHasher.hash(DefaultStreamHasher.java:35)
        ... 124 more
```

I also see errors about reading other files:

`2020-11-09T18:21:51.998-0800 [INFO] [org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DirectorySnapshotter] Could not read file path 'C:\Users\Me\myproject\.gradle\6.6.1\fileContent\fileContent.lock'.`

(the above is followed by an identical pair of exceptions about the MD5 hash and some other process locking a portion of the file)

`2020-11-09T18:21:52.029-0800 [INFO] [org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DirectorySnapshotter] Could not read file path 'C:\Users\Me\myproject\.gradle\6.6.1\fileHashes\fileHashes.lock'.`

(same)

Note that the entire project builds and runs correctly on Windows 10. This is *only* a problem running the tests.  But I'd love to get it resolved so that the Windows devs can run them.

I've tried the following things, none of which worked.

- Fresh checkout of the project on different machines
- Removing the project's `.gradle` folder and clean rebuilding
- sacrificing a very small goat

At first I thought the error might be caused by some failing tests (I had some integration tests that didn't run on Windows 10), but after disabling those, I (and my teammates) still get the error.

Note that a very similar question was asked, in context of building inside a Docker container:  [OSError: Can not read file in context: \\?\C:\project\.gradle\6.6.1\executionHistory\executionHistory.lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64574922)

However, we are **not** building inside Docker containers, and the solution above did not work for us.  I am building in a VirtualBox Windows 10 guest VM on a Mac OS Catalina host, and my teammate who is also seeing the error is building on a Windows 10 laptop.  No Docker is involved here.

I welcome ideas on how to help diagnose this problem further.  Note that it will be impractical to try to narrow it down to a small sample repro case, because of the size and ancient-ness of the project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle build error on Windows "Failed to create MD5 hash for file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48632019/gradle-build-error-on-windows-failed-to-create-md5-hash-for-file)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and solved it with the answers of [Gradle build error on Windows "Failed to create MD5 hash for file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48632019/gradle-build-error-on-windows-failed-to-create-md5-hash-for-file)

> The issue here is that the destination directory contains the .gradle directory, which is used by the initial gradle process and is thus locked in Windows. Then the daemon tries to hash the lockfile, because it hashes all files in the destination dir to check if the task is up to date, but since it is a lockfile, it can't be accessed by any other process.
> The solution is to set the output directory of the task to a folder where it can't interfere with any locked files.

To sum up, you can solve your issue by running your gradlew with a flag like:

```
--project-cache-dir=../cache
```